# Array with defined key and multidimensional

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've looked at other similar posts with no help, they all start with a multidimensional array already made, I want to make one by using the .push method

My array is:

```
ItemsArray.push({ 
    BMW:{Model:X5,Model:X6,Model:X3 },
    Range Rover:{Model:Sports,Model:Venar}
});
```

The car make is defined by buttons so if the user clicks Fiat then the list generates models such as `{Model: Punto}` and pushes into the above array with `Fiat:{Model: Punto}`.

I tried using: `ItemsArray[CarName].Models.push` but it gave error

> ItemsArray[CarName].Item' is not defined

Comment: Can you show how `ItemsArray` is defined?

Comment: ItemsArray = {}

Comment: In that case, `ItemsArray.push` is not defined. Further, if you call `ItemsArray[CarName].Models.push` then a few things have to be true in order for it to work: `ItemsArray[CarName]` has to be defined. It has to have the property `Models`, and that property needs to be an array.

Comment: just to elucidate: `ItemsArray = {}` you didn't create an array, you created an object. to create a real array, use
`ItemsArray = []` <-- this creates an array.

Comment: changing to [] didn't resolve the problem. still same error

Comment: Ok, the problem is another one, I was just saying that you are talking about array, but you're technically not using one, you are using an object, which is different

Comment: I have managed to define the array which works fine but now when I try to add a model into this array it only allows one item.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what your input is and what you like as output? For example: `{Model:X5,Model:X6,Model:X3 }`  doesn't make any sense.

Comment: HMR: We have a dozen buttons with Model makes on it. When users click Model X6 it pushes into an array.

Comment: You have no `Item` property in your array values. If you just want the car model object, it should just be `ItemsArray[CarName]`

Answer (score 0):

Part of the code you provided will never work. This for instance: `BMW:{Model:X5,Model:X6,Model:X3 }`. It constructs an object and you're adding the same property, `Model`, three times. The result is this object: `{ Model: X3 }`. Instead of an object you would have to use an array for this, like I did in my example below.

Besides that, using a array to store all data in is kind of impractical. You would get data structure like this:

```js
[
  {
    brand: 'BMW',
    models: [
      name: 'X5'
    ]
  },
  {
    brand: 'Fiat',
    models: [
      name: '500'
    ]
  },  
]
```

Now whenever you want to add a model to a brand, you first have to look for an entry in the array where the brand property matches the brand you want to add a model to. Only after doing this can you start manipulating the models for the brand.

I think that what you want to do is have an object which has a property per brand. Under this property you can store an array with models for that brand. I've mocked something up in the following snippet.

```js
const
  // This object will get an property per brand.
  modelsPerBrand = {},
  // An array with the brand we support.
  brands = ['BMW', 'Ford', 'Fiat'];

/**
 * This method will add a single model to a single brand.
 */
function addModelToBrand(brand, model) {
  const
    vehicles = modelsPerBrand[brand];
  if (vehicles === undefined) {
    // Log a message or alternatively add the new brand to the modelsPerBrand object.
    console.log(`Unknown brand "${ brand }"`);
    return;
  } 
  
  // Add the provided model to the array of models for the brand.
  vehicles.push({ name: model });
}

/**
 * This method makes it easy to add multiple models at once to a
 * single car brand.
 */
function addModelsToBrand(brand, models) {
  if (modelsPerBrand[brand] === undefined) {
    console.log(`Unknown brand "${ brand }"`);
    return;  
  }
  
  models.forEach(model => addModelToBrand(brand, model));
}

// Create an empty array for each brand. It will result in an object
// like this:
// {
//   BMW: [],
//   Ford: [],
//   Fiat: []
// }
brands.forEach(brand => modelsPerBrand[brand] = []);
console.log('Object with brands: ', modelsPerBrand);

// Add a single model to a brand. The object we have will now look
// like this:
// {
//   BMW: [ { name: 'X5' } ],
//   Ford: [],
//   Fiat: []
// }
addModelToBrand('BMW', 'X5');
console.log('Object after adding BMW X5: ', modelsPerBrand);

// Add a multiple models to a brand
addModelsToBrand('Fiat', ['500', '500L']);
console.log('Object after adding Fiat 500 and 500L: ', modelsPerBrand);

// Add model to non-existing brand
addModelsToBrand('KIA', 'Stinger');

// List all models for a brand:
modelsPerBrand.Fiat.forEach(model => console.log(`Fiat ${ model.name }`));
```

Alternatively you could use a `Map` instead of an object for the `vehiclesPerBrand` variable but I wasn't sure how you were planning on using it. That's why I went with an `Object` instead.